# Where do I store files for the src method?

Tags: javascript, src

I am learning JavaScript and there is this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="myjava.js">
</script>`

Where would I store "myjava.js"? Would it find it if the file is on my desktop?

Comment: Store it on your project folder and give the complete path in src attribute

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. They are totally different.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the javascript file in the same folder your html file is residing. I highly discourage the use of absolute path to specify the **src** since you will have to edit the references once you move your file from one place to another. Also, a good organization is necessary while writing web apps so I recomment you to create a proper directory structure such as:

```
webroot
    yourpage.html
    js
        myjava.js
    css
        styles.css
    images
        1.jpg
```

With such directory organization, your work looks properly structured. So now you can reference the javascript file as `<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/myjava.js"> </script>`

Answer (score 1):

For static html pages, the JavaScript file must be in the same folder as the html file, from which it is called. Otherwise you should use a relative path - *../path/somefolder/myjava.js* or full path.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/USER/Desktop/some.js"></script>
```

Comment: Say I am calling it from the URL bar...?

Comment: @nPwn, forget about the URL bar, it's a marginal way to run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The value value of the `src` attribute of a `<script>` element is the URL to a script file. This URL can be relative or absolute.

If the page containing the `<script>` element is located at, for example, `http://mysite.net/someDir/myPage.htm`, and the script file is in the same directory, you can use any of the following for your `src` attribute.

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<script src="/someDir/myscript.js"></script>
<script src="//mysite.net/someDir/myscript.js"></script>
<script src="http://mysite.net/someDir/myscript.js"></script>
```

If you are loading the page from your computer, save the script file in the same directory as your html file, and use a relative path.